# If I copy my DB to another system in the same directory will it work properly?

Tags: mysql, wamp

If I copy my DB from the phpmyadmin folder i.e. wamp/bin/mysql/mysql(version)/data/DBname, to another system in the same directory will it work properly?

Comment: yes it will work, make sure you shutdown mysql before copying just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to do is to create a new database in MySQL (eg `new_database`), then stop it/shut it down, then copy the files from within `wamp/bin/mysql/mysql(version)/data/DBname` to `wamp/bin/mysql/mysql(version)/data/new_database` and restart MySQL.

This will only work for databases with MyISAM tables not InnoDB tables.